# How to skip an iteration in a for in loop JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to able to skip an iteration in this for in break is just stopping it..

```js
   for (const property in data) {
              if (property === 'user' && !context.user) {
                break;
              }
              localStorage.setItem(property, data[property]);
          
            }
```

How to skip an iteration if certain condition is met in a for loop

Comment: [continue statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue)

Comment: Like in any other loop: you `continue` it

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are using the `break`, it will exit the loop. Using `continue` to skip current looping, and jump to next round.

```
for (const property in data) {
    if (property === 'user' && !context.user) {
        continue;
    }
    localStorage.setItem(property, data[property]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `continue` instead of `break`

OR

```
for (const property in data) {
  if (property !== "user" || context.user) {
    localStorage.setItem(property, data[property]);
  }
}
```